# Display other module on payment methods

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment-methods, gift-card

I am using a gift card extension(AheadWorks) in magento community ver. 1.9.0.1
i am trying to display the gift card block on payment methods section as other methods are displaying.

there can be two way what i think:
1) Calling that block on payment methods section after payment methods
2) I need to override the Payment Block in gift card extension.

Please suggest with some code hint.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: Hi Thanh TN, sorry i didn't find anything.

Comment: Sad, but thanks for the reply :D